# How do I search element from another worksheet?

Tags: excel

Worksheet 1 is a material movement record: it has a column of material names("A1", "A2") and a column of quantity in unit.
Worksheet 2 is a material package information: it has a column of material names (more material types than worksheet 1) and a column of unit type ("Piece", "Pack", etc).
I want to use material name A1 in worksheet 1 to search that material A1 in worksheet 2 and copy the corresponding unit type from worksheet 2 and paste it to worksheet 1 separate column that matches the same material as A1.
What should I do about this case?

Comment: This belongs on https://superuser.com/ instead of Stack Overflow. You're really just talking about a basic `=VLOOKUP()` formula. This also means that you should probably just search Super User and you'll find good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Sheet2` is as follows:

[image]

and `Sheet1` is

[image]

Then in `Cell C1` of `Sheet1` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$7,2)
```

Drag/Copy down this formula as required and change `Range A2:B7` as per your data.